# Blank page when try to login to facebook within webView

Tags: java, android, webview

i use android studio to  create webView.
the code work OK, but the problem is when i try to do login with Facebook after i type the username and password i got a blank page.
can someone help me and open my eyes what what I'm missing?

this is the code in the MainActivity.java

```
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
    // Enable Javascript
    WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://dosisearch.com/");
```

Comment: so, I succeeded to solved it with  prevent Facebook oauth to display popup.

Answer (score 2):

Nothing is wrong with your code. It is the website "http://dosisearch.com/" which is having the problem :) When you click on login it displays a pop up window, maybe because of this you are not able to see it in a WebView. Try to use a different URL and check whether it is working fine.

Comment: but the website and the login to facebook work OK. just within the webview the facebook login revice a blankpage.

Comment: @MatiShwartz when you click on login it displays a pop up window..maybe because of this you are not able to see it in a webview. Try to use a different url and check whether it is working fine.

Comment: thanks, you right about it that the code is OK the problem is on web-view and popup.

Comment: @MatiShwartz If my answer was helpful, please accept it, thanks! :)